# I18N Date Format String

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, internationalization, datetime-format

I am working on internationalizing a project that has a custom date picker. The en-US version displays a message like to the user "Invalid date, valid format is mm/dd/yyyy." The "Invalid date, valid format is mm/dd/yyyy" is a resource string. The allows for the date format to be customized from the culture default so simply translating the 'mm/dd/yyyy' part is not an option. I know how to get the date format from the current culture (in .net) but I was wondering if there a way translate the m's, d's, and y's or what the generally accepted practice for this type of problem is?

Comment: I have no experience in internationalizing, but I think you can use a fixed datetime format like this  
           
`var datetime = DateTime.ParseExact("20120120 18:20:22 +0000", "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss zzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`
        
`var str = datetime.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss zzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: The issue is not parsing a string that the user is inputting but rather displaying the appropriate error message when the user inputs something that is invalid. Example -- in France the date format is mm/dd/yyyy (which is the format that the system should accept when the culture is fr-FR). Also in French day is jour , month is mois, and year is annee. So the error message might display mm/jj/aaaa (assuming that this is how they do a date format in french).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to externalize it that is move it to resource file. There is no practice as such, but what I could recommend is to actually generate the entry from DateTimeFormatInfo (there is a format switch "g" that gives you so-called general, that is default date & time format). Adding appropriate comment won't hurt either.